# Android sort sqlite query results ignoring case

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, uppercase, lowercase

just wondering if theres a way of sorting the results of a query ignoring case. Cause at the moment fields starting with an upper case letter are sorted and put on top of the list and fields starting with lower case letter are also sorted but are put after the upper case fields.

Thanks --
Mike

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`ORDER BY column COLLATE NOCASE;`

See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation

Comment: I tried doing this and was getting the error `SQLiteException: near "COLLATE": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column ASC COLLATE NOCASE`. The solution is to remove the `ASC` and only specify the direction when it is `DESC`.

Comment: @unchek — Also try [`COLLATE NOCASE ASC`](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#ordering-term).

Comment: @plowman Just like aaz said, the ASC or DESC should be after the NOCASE.

Answer (score 1):

On the Android you are given a collation function called LOCALIZED.

When you specify your column, do the following:

CREATE TABLE song(..., title TEXT COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC, ...)

It works great.  If you have the Android source code, just do a search for "COLLATE" to see all sorts of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all entries to lower case for example: select name from table order by LCASE(name)

LCASE or LOWER (Check documentation)

Comment: Cheers for the reply mate...the other method was easier though :)