# Order database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I gave an sqlite database and I want to query the database ordered by name.

I heard that you can do this by the orderBy part in the db.query code. So I did it like this where KEY_NAME is supposed to sort it by name.

The reason It isn't going in order is because it is treating caps and non caps as two separate things so if its a caps S and a lower case a, S will go before a is there anyway to ignore caps

```
// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, null, null, null, null, KEY_NAME, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Did you try explicitly adding the sort order? something like `, KEY_NAME + " ASC",`

Comment: Also, it doesn't sound like this has anything to do with MySQL, I recommend removing that tag.

Comment: just tried same thing "s" still comes before "a"

Comment: If you don't have a lot of rows, can you edit your question to show the order of results you are getting?

Comment: On further inspection it seems not to be able to order the ones already there. It will put it in alphabetical order if I add a new row though

Comment: Ok new question The reason It isn't going in order is because it is treating caps and non caps as two separate things so if its a caps S and a lower case a, S will go before a is there anyway to ingnore caps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917545/android-sort-sqlite-query-results-ignoring-case

Comment: I can't get anything form the link can you provide an example

Comment: it's an order by clause. change KEY_NAME in your example to KEY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE"

Comment: Ohh It wasn't working because I was missing the COLLATE part. Thank You It worked